# Having options in argparse with a dash

Tags: python, argparse

I want to have some options in argparse module such as `--pm-export` however when I try to use it like `args.pm-export` I get the error that there is not attribute `pm`. How can I get around this issue? Is it possible to have `-` in command line options?

Answer (score 365, accepted):

From [the `argparse` docs](http://docs.python.org/dev/library/argparse.html#dest):

> For optional argument actions, the value of `dest` is normally inferred from the option strings. `ArgumentParser` generates the value of `dest` by taking the first long option string and stripping away the initial `--` string. Any internal **`-` characters will be converted to `_` characters** to make sure the string is a valid attribute name.

So you should be using `args.pm_export`.

Answer (score 161):

Unfortunately, dash-to-underscore replacement doesn't work for positional arguments (arguments not prefixed by `--`).
For example:

```
import argparse
import sys

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('logs-dir',
                    help='Directory with .log and .log.gz files')
parser.add_argument('results-csv', type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                    default=sys.stdout,
                    help='Output .csv filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
# Namespace(**{'logs-dir': './', 'results-csv': <_io.TextIOWrapper name='mydata.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>})
```

So, you should use the first argument to `add_argument()` for the attribute name and pass a `metavar` kwarg to set how it should be displayed in help:

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process some integers.')
parser.add_argument('logs_dir', metavar='logs-dir',
                    help='Directory with .log and .log.gz files')
parser.add_argument('results_csv', metavar='results-csv',
                    type=argparse.FileType('w'),
                    default=sys.stdout,
                    help='Output .csv filename')
args = parser.parse_args()

print(args)
# Namespace(logs_dir='./', results_csv=<_io.TextIOWrapper name='mydata.csv' mode='w' encoding='UTF-8'>)
```

Comment: The relevant Python bug report: http://bugs.python.org/issue15125.  `argparse` uses `setattr` and `getattr`, so `dest` names do not have to be valid `dot` attribute names.  The user can also use `getattr`.

Comment: I'd just do `positional_arg = getattr( parser, 'positional-arg' )`

Comment: I think it's: `positional_arg = getattr(args, 'positional-arg')` For me at least.

Answer (score 27):

Dashes are converted to underscores:

```
import argparse
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('--foo-bar')
args = parser.parse_args(['--foo-bar', '24'])
print(args)  # Namespace(foo_bar='24')
```

Answer (score 4):

Concise and explicit but probably not always acceptable way would be to use `vars()`:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('a-b')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())

print(args['a-b'])
```

Answer (score 2):

**`getattr(args, 'positional-arg')`**

This is another OK workaround for positional arguments:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument('a-b')
args = parser.parse_args(['123'])
assert getattr(args, 'a-b') == '123'
```

Tested on Python 3.8.2.

Comment: This will not pass if `a-b` is not a positional argument, which is required by the question.

Answer (score -1):

I guess the last option is to change shorten option `-a` to `--a`

```
import argparse

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description="Help")
parser.add_argument("--a", "--argument-option", metavar="", help="")   # change here
args = parser.parse_args()
option = args.a                # And here
print(option)
```

Comment: Please don't do this. We have a convention that `-` is for short one letter arguments and `--` is for long arguments, life is easier if we all stick to it.